# Java Inference variable T has incompatible bounds

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to make a custom entity component system in java and I am having some difficulty with type erasure. The whole system functions properly save one method. I want to be able to call a generic method `createEntity(Class<? extends Component>... types);` which receives a var args array of types, creates a new blank entity, and adds new components of the specified types using reflection. Here is the method that I have written.

```
public Entity createEntity(Class<? extends Component>... types){
    Entity e = new Entity();  
    for(Class<? extends Component> type: types){
        try {
            getParent().getComponentManager().add(type, e.UID, type.newInstance());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }              
    INDEX.add(e.UID, e);
    return e;
}
```

This is the line that is creating the compile error.

```
getParent().getComponentManager().add(type, e.UID, type.newInstance());
```

This is the method inside of the `ComponentManager` class.

```
public <T extends Component> void add(Class<T> type, int uid, T component){
    if(component != null){
        ComponentIndex<T> index = getComponentsByType(type);
        if(!index.has(uid)){
            index.add(uid, component);
            component.setParent(this);
        }
    }        
}
```

The `Component` class is just an empty interface.

```
public interface Component{}
```

The error that I keep getting from the NetBeans tool tip is something along the lines of

> ...method add in class ComponentManager cannot be applied to given types;
>    required: Class, int, T
>    found: Class, int, Class
>    reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds...

How do I use reflection to create a Component based on a generic `Class<?>` given that all components will implement the `Component` interface, and all components will have a constructor with no arguments ?

Comment: Not sure but if you are `extending` an Interface then it will still be an `interface`

Comment: I meant to say that all components will be implementing the `Component` interface.

Comment: so shouldn't you use `implements` not `extends` ?

Comment: therefore the semantic change I made in the edit^ 
_"given that all components will implement the Component interface"_

Comment: What version of Java are you compiling with?  Type inference has changed since Java 8, and I'm not able to recreate this using Java 9 in Intellij IDEA.

Comment: this is using java 8, I can try with java 9.

Comment: I installed intelliJ with jdk 9 and imported all of my source code into a new project, but I am still getting the same issue. What did you do to try and recreate the problem? The main issue seems to be that `T`, `?`, and `capture of ?` are all incompatible. It also seems that `type.newInstance()` is now deprecated, is there a suggested replacement for it in java 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the solution to this particular issue after reading this article. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html

The problem is that when using wildcards the compiler cannot guarantee that  objects are of the correct type, but by using a generic helper method you can ensure type safety for each element by capturing the type of the wildcard. In this case, this is the helper method that I used.

```
private <T extends Component> void addNewComponentInstance(Class<T> type, int uid){
    try {
        getParent().getComponentManager().add(type, uid, type.newInstance());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is how it was sandwiched into the wildcard method.

```
public Entity createEntity(Class<? extends Component>... types){
    Entity e = new Entity();  
    for(Class<? extends Component> type: types)
        addNewComponentInstance(type, e.UID);                   
    INDEX.add(e.UID, e);
    return e;
}
```

This solution compiles and runs correctly.